# Matching variable to every 4th number in a loop - PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I am needing to add a different class at the end of every 4th item that I am looping through. I have done so by:

```
$i=0;
foreach($mount as $m){
    $i++;
    $startClass = '';
    if($i==4||$i==8||$i==12){$startClass='<div with class>';} //adds class on 4th intervals
    $ret.=''.$startClass.'<other HTML here and such>'; //shorted for readability
}
```

Now I'm sure there is a more appropriate way to handle this given the fact that if my loop contains 40 objects, I'll need to adjust the `if` statement accordingly.

I'm recalling an arithmetic formula that might work `[an = a1+(n-1)d]` but I'm finding that my idea seems off. I apply it (replacing an with i) and it will always = to the equation, thus each item gets the class.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulus operator
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

```
if(($i % 4) === 0){
  //add class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of the [`foreach` control structure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and the [`%` modulus](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator will give you what you need:

```
foreach ($mount as $key => $m) {
    if ($key % 4 == 0) {
        $startClass = '<div with class>';
    } else {
        $startClass = '';
    }
    $ret.=''.$startClass.'<other HTML here and such>';
}
```

The `foreach` hash-rocket (`=>`) notation enables you to pass the index of the current element being iterated through. You can use the index to keep track of the *nth*-object.

The modulus operator returns the remainder from division; if the remainder is zero, the divisor is a factor of the dividend and thus can be used to calculate *nth*-factors.

Comment: Really great info here, thank you for the input! Well documented, too. Cheers!

Comment: @ride_85027, if this answer helped address your question (which it evidently did), please consider upvoting it.

Comment: That up vote you see is from me, the day I wrote you back. If there is something else that I am missing, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is **modulo** operator

example:

```
if($i%4 == 0){$startClass='<div with class>';}
```

which means that *i = k + 0*, *k* being *integer*

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;

foreach($mount as $m)
{
    if (($i++ % 4) == 0)
    {

    }
}
```